# How to get the object who instantiated a class

Tags: python, cpython

I have the following situation: I have multiple classes who gets instantiated everywhere in my application. I want every object to get an id from the parent object (saying that I have object B and object B instantiate object C then object B is the parent of object C but object C can be also parent for other objects, i'm not talking inheritance).

What I can guarantee is that all classes inherits from the same base class, let's say rootobject class and I can work on this.

I really want to avoid refactoring object instantiation since there are a huge amount of classes. Passing the self argument when object is instantiated is not an option, is too time consuming when you have a large code base.

I thought about an way on looking to the call stack frames and try to get from there the class who instantiated "me". It should be the previous frame but this implementation is too hackish.

Any ideas ?

Comment: How in god's name did this happen?

Comment: Inspecting the call stack is likely your best option. Be careful -  you could easily make all of your objects undeletable - `weakref` is your friend.

Comment: By "object B instantiates object C" do you mean "C is instantiated from within a method of B's class, where self=B"?

Comment: This is likely an XY problem. Please explain why you want to do that.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very hacky, but working solution:

```
import inspect

def get_instantiator():
    # The instantiator is two frames back.
    frame = inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_back
    frame_args = inspect.getargvalues(frame)
    return frame_args.locals[frame_args.args[0]]

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = B()

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.parent = get_instantiator()

a = A()
print(a.b.parent == a)
```

It finds the `self` argument passed into the instantiating class.